# Finding last empty row not working for one sheet only

Tags: vba, excel

My mind is broken. I have spent *days* trying to figure out why this is happening:

After a user form is filled out there is a button to populate a corresponding spreadsheet. The sheet is determined by the first combo box (`catSel.value`). To find the last empty row I use the `rngSrch` portion of the code below.

On one sheet `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Acell.EntireRow) = 0` comes back as false and `firstBlankRow = Acell.row` is not run.

I have tried deleting the sheet and creating a new one(copying one that works), changing the name and commenting out/changing the code.

Any ideas why this is happening? Also `ws.Range("A" & firstBlankRow) = Me.equipId.value` is coming back with `Run-time Error ‘1004’: method ‘Range’ of object ’_worksheet’ failed`

```
Private Sub AddCont_Click()

Dim firstBlankRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim srchRng As Range
Dim Acell As Range

Set ws = Worksheets(CatSel.value)

On Error GoTo Err


With ws
    Set srchRng = .UsedRange.Columns(1).Find("") 
    If Not srchRng Is Nothing Then
        Set srchRng =.UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        For Each Acell In srchRng
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Acell.EntireRow) = 0     Then
                firstBlankRow = Acell.row
                Exit For

            End If

        Next
    Else
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then 
            MsgBox "Please start a new sheet"
        Else
            firstBlankRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).row + 1

        End If
    End If



'Equipment ID
    ws.Range("A" & firstBlankRow) = Me.equipId.value
'Parent or Next Level
    ws.Range("B" & firstBlankRow) = Me.NextLev.value
'Keyword
    ws.Range("C" & firstBlankRow) = Me.KeySel.value
'Cost Center
    ws.Range("E" & firstBlankRow) = Me.CostSel.value
'Department
    ws.Range("F" & firstBlankRow) = Me.DepartSel.value
'Location 1
    ws.Range("G" & firstBlankRow) = Me.Loc1.value
'Location 2
    ws.Range("H" & firstBlankRow) = Me.Loc2.value
'Location 3
    ws.Range("I" & firstBlankRow) = Me.Loc3.value
'Location 4
    ws.Range("J" & firstBlankRow) = Me.Loc4.value
'Beginning of specs
'L5
    ws.Range("L" & firstBlankRow) = Me.L3Sel.value
'M5
    ws.Range("M" & firstBlankRow) = Me.M3Sel.value
'N5
    ws.Range("N" & firstBlankRow) = Me.N3sel.value
'O5
    ws.Range("O" & firstBlankRow) = Me.O3Sel.value
'P5
    ws.Range("P" & firstBlankRow) = Me.P3Sel.value
'Q5
    ws.Range("Q" & firstBlankRow) = Me.Q3Sel.value
'R5
    ws.Range("R" & firstBlankRow) = Me.R3Sel.value
'S5
    ws.Range("S" & firstBlankRow) = Me.S3Sel.value
'T5
    ws.Range("T" & firstBlankRow) = Me.T3Sel.value
'U5
    ws.Range("U" & firstBlankRow) = Me.U3Sel.value

    MsgBox ("successfully Added")

End With

Err: MsgBox ("something went wrong")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** in this part of the code

```
Set srchRng = .UsedRange.Columns(1).Find("") 
If Not srchRng Is Nothing Then
    Set srchRng =.UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    For Each Acell In srchRng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Acell.EntireRow) = 0     Then
            firstBlankRow = Acell.row
            Exit For

        End If

    Next
Else
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then 
        MsgBox "Please start a new sheet"
    Else
        firstBlankRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).row + 1

    End If
End If
```

you are trying to find the first blank row, so that you can insert a new record.

If so, I suggest you replace that code with:

```
If IsEmpty(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)) Then
    firstBlankRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Else
    MsgBox "Please start a new sheet"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

That code will look for the last non-empty cell in column A and set the `firstBlankRow` variable to point to the row after it.

---

If your records sometimes have an empty value in column A, but you have another column that **can** be guaranteed to always have a value, just change the above code to refer to that column instead of to column 1.  E.g. (assuming column D is always populated):

```
If IsEmpty(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D")) Then
    firstBlankRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Else
    MsgBox "Please start a new sheet"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

---

If you have records where **no** column is guaranteed to be non-empty, perhaps this code will work:

```
firstBlankRow = .Rows.Count + 1
If IsEmpty(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A")) Then
    For firstBlankRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 To .Rows.Count
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(firstBlankRow)) = 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
If firstBlankRow = .Rows.Count + 1 Then
    MsgBox "Please start a new sheet"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: So this worked! BUT, It went to the first empty cell in column A. Any way to get this to look for the first completely empty row?

Comment: @ShawnTaylor - Judging by the data that you were putting into the sheets, I expected column A would always be populated if anything was in the row, but I have updated the answer to cater for the situation where none of the columns in a row can be guaranteed to be filled in.